# Codeigniter Auto complete Multiple fields not working Properly

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I want to use jQuery auto complete multiple Fields in codeigniter framework I referred [this](http://www.smarttutorials.net/jquery-autocomplete-multiple-fields-using-ajax-php-mysql-example/) tutorial.But my search filed not working.text fields doesn't show auto complete list
here is my code please help me to solve this.

view
.....................

```
<div class="row">
    <form action="" name="students" method="post" id="students">
        <input type="text" name="patientId" id="patientId_1" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname_1" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
        <input type="text" name="nic" id="nic_1" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
        <input type="text" name="telephone" id="telephone_1" class="ui-autocomplete-input">
    </form>
</div>
```

jQuery
.......

```
$('#patientId_1').autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url : 'http://localhost/cafdc/BillingController/test',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    name_startsWith: request.term,
                    type: 'patient_table',
                    row_num : 1
                },
                success: function( data ) {
                    response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                        var code = item.split("|");
                        return {
                            label: code[0],
                            value: code[0],
                            data : item
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 0,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            var names = ui.item.data.split("|");
            $('#firstname_1').val(names[1]);
            $('#nic_1').val(names[2]);
            $('#telephone_1').val(names[3]);
        }
    });
```

controller
.......................

```
public function test()
        {
            $data=$this->Billing_Model->get_data();
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
```

model
....................

```
 public function get_data()
    {
        if($_POST['type'] == 'patient_table'){
            $row_num = $_POST['row_num'];
            $result =$this->db->query( "SELECT  patientId, fname, nic, tpnumber FROM tblpatient where name LIKE '".strtoupper($_POST['name_startsWith'])."%'");
            $data = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $name = $row['patientId'].'|'.$row['fname'].'|'.$row['nic'].'|'.$row['tpnumber'].'|'.$row_num;
                array_push($data, $name);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: `id` must be unique if there are multiple elements having same `id` and you are applying autocomplete to them, it will not allow/work as expected.

Comment: you are talking about which  id?

Comment: Obviously on which you initialized `autocomplete` plugin thats `patientId`.

Comment: But there is no duplicate patientId...hmm bit confusing

Comment: I changed my code(Please check the edited one) but still same issue auto complete not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87751/discussion-between-h-swan-and-rohan-kumar).

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not working Because you are not `return` any data from model

```
public function get_data()
    {
        if($_POST['type'] == 'patient_table'){
            $row_num = $_POST['row_num'];
            $result =$this->db->query( "SELECT  patientId, fname, nic, tpnumber FROM tblpatient where name LIKE '".strtoupper($_POST['name_startsWith'])."%'");
            $data = array();
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $name = $row['patientId'].'|'.$row['fname'].'|'.$row['nic'].'|'.$row['tpnumber'].'|'.$row_num;
                array_push($data, $name);
            }
            return $data;// return your data

        }
    }
```

Comment: what error you get??Also check your browser console for error!!

Comment: I don't get any errors.but auto complete not working

Comment: `alert(data);` inside `success: function( data ) {` and check the result

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `type:"POST"` in ajax call otherwise it will take it as `GET` so add the `type` in your `$.ajax` call like,

```
$.ajax({
   url:'...',
   type:"POST",// add this line in your ajax call
   ....
})
```